# Display and submit a Webform as part of another form?

Tags: webforms

I have a form that users submit to build a custom entity. I need to add an optional Webform to the bottom of my form. When my form is submitted, I need to save the custom entity, then set a hidden Webform input with the new entity ID and submit the Webform. Should I do this with Subform?

Comment: I don't know what subform is, but you could do this with Rules and the Webform integration.  You could automatically generate the webform on entity save and use the set data value action as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But, I need to display and collect a few fields of the Webform, so generating the Webform later would require building the elements myself and then copying those values in to the generated Webform. This might still be a way to do it, but I'll hold out for a way that has Webform build itself.